How should I ask my boss to fire me?
I started out my current job with good intentions, but it's not working out and it's been a few years.
I consistently under-perform, miss deadlines, feel like I'm blown about like the wind in my role, and I'm consistently of no value to my team despite being in a senior role. My manager has grown frustrated and I know there is no upward mobility at this company for me.
Whenever my fingers touch my keyboard my soul screams at me and I'm flown a decade into the past when I actually had something resembling a creative spark and potential, but they're not firing me! I'm missing critical things in my life and I blame my profession and resent my job.
How do I tell my boss? I've actually already told him to fire me but that hasn't worked. I'd like to collect unemployment while I think things over with some free time, but I'll need some income in order for this to be a good trade so I can't resign myself. If you've needed to be fired before, what did you do?

Does your boss agree with your assessment of your value?

@JoeStrazzere What do you mean "Why should they fire me"? I cost money and add no value. Am I missing something about how companies work?

@Raven - Many companies keep people who are useless at their job, because it costs more and is a greater risk to fire them. Your Salary is likely less than the cost of a lawsuit. If they are unwilling to fire you and you are unable to improve - collect the paycheque and enjoy it.

@Raven Why do you think so lowly of your manager?

@Helena I don't he's fine and competent, he's just too nice and gives too many second chances to people like me who should obviously be let go

@Raven but you still think they would see someone as "worthless" or "retard" which is not how a decent percent would think about anyone.

Depending on where you live, "being fired" may not get you unemployment benefits while "being laid off" will get you unemployment benefits. Please add your country tag.

Reading this, you should consult a health professional. Your attitude towards yourself is not healthy. You should no more try to fix this yourself than trying to fix a broken bone yourself. Critically, depending on where you are in the world you should talk to a doctor while you are still employed.

@MisterMiyagi that stuff isn't real.
Update: Had a talk with my manager yesterday. Got a few good words out of him concerning my future at the company and, as I figured, every assumption I had was true. Wrote down some of the better tidbits and agreed to leave in 2 weeks. As expected they were sort of not including me and were going to throw a PIP my way designed to fail. The longer story is I was hired for one part of the project I'm suited for but couldn't get anything done because me and the other guy hate each other. I wasn't a good fit for the other end and the project is closing now.

I’m voting to close this question because this sounds unethical and/or fraudulent


I'd like to collect unemployment while I think things over with some free time, but I'll need some income in order for this to be a good trade so I can't resign myself.

That's just not how things work. You can't just decide to walk away and get a free income just because you feel like having some free time.
Just to be clear, I am not glossing over things like PTO, mental health leave, and similar reasons where ensuring income is justifiable. I'm very much in favor of those initiatives. But that's not what this is. You don't like your job, you don't want to do it, but you want to instead just collect a free income because otherwise it won't "be a good trade for you".
Do you want a salary? Find a new job. Don't want to work? Well then why should you be paid?
This question boils down to a disagreement on the conditions for collecting an unemployment benefit, which is not something that anyone here can change for you - nor am I convinced that they should even if they could.

Additionally, depending on where you live unemployment isn't so easy to collect, you have to be actively searching for employment. Every day I had to log applications sent and a number of interviews. There was a quota to meet before I could even collect.

The world doesn't owe you a paycheck while you ponder your future.
How about figure out what you have a passion for and put out your resume?
Getting a job that you like seems like a better plan than hoping to be fired.
This is just my opinion as an business owner.

Put yourself in your boss's shoes. He's had years in which if he genuinely rated you as "worthless" he could have put you on a PIP, seen you fail and got rid of you at any point. He hasn't done that. Then you ask to be fired, when you're perfectly capable of resigning. That's sufficiently off the wall that he's going to try to work out your motives, and probably sees one of:

you're angling for unemployment benefit to which you wouldn't otherwise be entitled (i.e. fraud)
you're angling him into a position where you deny you asked to be fired, and claim unfair dismissal and compensation
your mental health is shot to pieces and when you recover, you claim inadequate support (probably rightly, if they've not offered anything up to this point) and unfair dismissal

Of course he cannot reasonably go along with any of these scenarios. It's a lot lower risk to him to leave things be and hope that if you're serious about leaving, you resign or give him watertight cause to fire you. Or, the company reorganises and it becomes someone else's problem.
For your own good, you need to be planning your departure now - working out what you want to do next while you still have a job (it's always easier to get a new job while you are still employed - and imagine how you would explain your firing to an interviewer!), and getting some external help to understand yourself and why this job is trashing you mentally. So that you don't simply walk into the same situation again.

Had a talk with my manager and confirmed all my suspicions based on corporate movements. Better performers are being moved to broader projects, lower performers are going to receive PIPs and fired. I decided to resign and wrote down a couple of banger quotes from his end in the meeting. I'm not going to work for a while because this experience was horrible. I own my own house and have a fatass savings. Next time I work I'll resolve to be right next to the money or not work there at all.

In the vast majority of US states, you have to be laid off to collect unemployment.  You are not eligible if you are fired "for cause."  As such, most companies, especially those who are self-insured, are not interested in laying you off just to pay you unemployment for fun.  They will fire you or you can quit.

When the state is running the unemployment insurance, the rate the company pays goes up when they have laid someone off.
